# javascript reduce on properties of an array of objects acting weird

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
parts: [
      {
        name: 'Fundamentals of React',
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Using props to pass data',
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'State of a component',
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Redux',
        exercises: 11,
        id: 4
      }
    ]
```

I would like to get the sum of the excercises. I'm trying to accomplish it thusly:

```
const Total = (props) => {

  const total = props.parts.reduce( (prev, cur) => {
    
    console.log('prev.excercises : ', prev.exercises)
    console.log('cur.excercises : ', cur.exercises)

    return prev.exercises + cur.exercises 
  })

  return (
    <>
      <p>Number of exercises {total}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

But this results in NaN. The console shows why this result occurs, but not why the prev.excercises value is acting weird:

```
prev.excercises :  10
cur.excercises :  7
prev.excercises :  undefined
cur.excercises :  14
prev.excercises :  undefined
cur.excercises :  11
```

I'm really new to js, so there is probably something really simple I'm doing wrong.. appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: You're not giving an initial value to `reduce`, thus `prev` will change from being an object the first iteration to being a number the second one. Please review how [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works because you're trying to do two conflicting things with it right now which would of course lead to weird results.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `reduce`. You don't have an initial variable. `prev.excercises` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Andy exists only the first time the function is called because without an explicit initial value, the first item in the array becomes the initial value.

Comment: you should change `return prev.exercises + cur.exercises` to `return prev + cur.exercises `

Comment: Technically, yes, but introducing steps to ensure that doesn't happen is important.

Comment: Yes, but the problem isn't that "it doesn't exist". The log shows it does. The problem is *it changes* which is what OP did not realise. And did not figure out by looking at the log output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access it as an object but are returning it as an integer

```
const Total = (props) => {

  const total = props.parts.reduce( (prev, cur) => {

    console.log('prev.excercises : ', prev.exercises)
    console.log('cur.excercises : ', cur.exercises)

    return {exercises : prev.exercises + cur.exercises}
  })
```

If you don't want to return object you can do it like this

```
const total = props.parts.reduce( (prev,    cur) => {
prev=typeof prev==="object" ?  prev.exercises:prev
console.log('prev.excercises : ', prev)
console.log('cur.excercises : ', cur.exercises)

return  prev+ cur.exercises  })
```

Comment: Thank You! This works. But as I sed, I'm new to javascript syntax and I really don't understand why this helps. I shall dive in to the documentation of reduce! Maybe there I will understand, why prev and cur are acting differently.

Comment: All the best in your journey learning javascript

Answer (score 0):

I also got it working like this, but I guess Ahmed Ali's answer is more to the nose!

```
const Total = (props) => {

  const total = props.parts.map(part => part.exercises).
  reduce((prev, cur) => {
    console.log('prev : ', prev)
    console.log('cur : ', cur)
    return prev + cur
  })
```